# In Dart, how do you set the number of decimals in a double variable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set a double, let's call it Price, in Dart, so that it always gives me a double of 2 decimal places.

So 2.5 would return 2.50 and 2.50138263 would also return 2.50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest answer would be double's built-in toStringAsFixed.

In your case

```
double x = 2.5;
print('${x.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
x = 2.50138263;
print('${x.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
```

Would both return 2.50. Be aware that this truncates (e.g., 2.519 returns 2.51). It does not use the standard rounding (half-even) banker's algorithm.

I recommend using a [NumberFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) from the intl package; The parsing and formatting rules are worth learning since they appear in other languages like Java.

```
double d = 2.519;
String s = NumberFormat.currency().format(d);
print(s);
```

returns USD2.52

```
s = NumberFormat('#.00').format(d);
```

returns 2.52

Since your are dealing with money, you should probably use [NumberFormat.currency](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.currency.html), which would add the currency symbol for the current locale.

Comment: Thanks.  The NumberFormat.currency was a nice suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about how Dart handles the type double. Something like the following might work depending on your use-case:

```
void main() {
  double num = 2.50138263;
  
  num = double.parse(num.toStringAsFixed(2));
  
  print(num);
}
```

More info about how Dart handles double can be found [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/double-class.html).

Comment: Thanks, I edited the title.  I want to keep the Price a double and not convert it to a string.

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer.